# How does fallthrough work with express.static()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, I've a basic express setup as shown below:

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Home Page");
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.send("About Page");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on PORT 3000");
});
```

In the code above `app.use()` middleware will be executed for every request because the default path for `app.use()` is `/`.

Now `express.static()` will be serving the `public` directory, so if I go to `/` route I will see the contents of the `index.html` file and the `app.get("/")` middleware will not get executed.

But when I go to `/about`, I see the contents sent from `app.get("/about")`. This is what I don't understand because according to docs it calls `next()` only when the file is not found, but when it is found the request stops there.

So, when I navigate to `/about`, `app.use()` will be the first to get executed and it will find `index.html` file and should render that, but instead it calls `next` and the `get` handler for about gets executed. WHY?

I am not very clear how static assets are being served, I guess when I go to `/about` it is not actually looking for `index.html` file but then what file is it looking for?

Comment: I think [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) is the answer to your question

Comment: The main point is here : `So, when I navigate to /about, app.use() will be the first to get executed and it will find index.html`.  It will find `/about/index.html` or `about.html`, not `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The root argument specifies the root directory from which to serve static assets. The function determines the file to serve by combining req.url with the provided root directory.

So, `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))` serves the `public` directory.

#### Visiting `/` route

Remember the file to serve will be determined by combining `req.url` with root. So, in this case `req.url` is `/` and root is `public`. So express will try to serve `public/index.html`, where `index.html` is the default, if no file is specified explicitly.

> Sends the specified directory index file. Set to false to disable directory indexing.

This file will be found and will be rendered and the request ends there, so the get handler for `/` is not executed.

You can set the `index` property to `false` and then express will not look for `index.html` file by default.

So, setting `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"), { index: false }))` will make express to not look for `index.html` file by default and now if you visit `/` route, the `get` handler for `/` will be executed.

#### Visiting `/about` route

This time `req.url` is `/about`, so express will try to serve `public/about/index.html`, which will not be found and therefore it calls `next()` and the get handler for `/about` gets executed.

#### Visiting `/about.html` route

This time `req.url` is `/about.html`, so express will try to serve `public/about.html` which if found will be rendered else `next()` will be called.

Answer (score 2):

From the `express.static()` documentation https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static:

*The function determines the file to serve by combining req.url with the provided root directory.*

Optionally, it will also look for a directory index file - see the `index` option.

So in your scenario:

- `/` will match the `index.html` file in your root directory.
- `/about` will try to match a file named `about`, or an `index.html` file in the `./about` subdirectory. If there is no such match, then the request will be passed on to the next middelware in line.